# Windows 10 repair requires usb

Tags: windows-10, reboot, bootrepair

I have an oldish laptop (Gateway NV59, from 2010, 8GB, upgraded to ssd) with Windows 10. The computer crashes fairly often for cooling reasons, which of course is not good, but please bear with me.

When booting after a crash, every single time the screen flashes and the system reboots into repair mode; no option for automatic repair is given. What I usually do is to shutdown the laptop, and boot it again, now with a Windows 10 install usb drive connected. Windows then boots normally, with a few seconds in a bluish screen, and goes to the login screen. The computer then works normally until the next crash.

While I understand that the laptop is not in top condition, I would like to be able to boot it without using the usb installation disk. Is there anything I can do to achieve this?

Comment: Place the WinRE environment on a partition on the system.  Are you actually booting to the USB drive, which contains the WinRE, or is something else happening?

Comment: No, the Windows system on the ssd boots (regular boot, nor offer of repair nor anything), but only when the usb with the installation files is plugged in.

Comment: This all the time or just when your system crashes?

Comment: Only when booting after a crash. A normal shutdown-boot sequence works flawlessly.

Comment: Have you done a thorough cleaning, including fans? It's easy to add supplemental fan cooling, too. You might also look into fan control software such as SpeedFan. This does not address the reboot issue, but should avoid the necessity. There is no intrinsic reason a PC should crash frequently from overheating,  even an older one,